# Grammaticality of "could you please, let us know when this issue is fixed?"

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

> Could you please, let us know when this issue is fixed?

Is this sentence grammatical?
I would like to ask someone to let me know when the issue is fixed

Comment: Yes. It is an idiomatic alternative for _“Could you please let us know when this issue has been fixed."_ (Notice: no comma, and I've omitted the question mark as I'm interpreting this as a polite request rather than a question, though the question mark is not wrong.)

Comment: I think it's a little wordy, and would *idiomatically* be something like *"Please ~follow-up and~ let us know when this issue has been fixed."* I would also suggest you replace "this issue" with **what** the **issue** is. It might be your brakes, your sink or your commode... presumably you want the **reader** *thinking* about what they're fixing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The words are acceptable but the punctuation is not.  Your two options for correct comma placement would be:

"Could you, please, let us know when …"

"Could you please let us know when …"

The version with two commas is somewhat outmoded; the version with none is readily understandable and more contemporary.  One comma alone, however, is incorrect.

Comment: The older version with the commas probably developed from "could you, _if you_ please, let us know when..."  Eventually the _if_ and _you_ got dropped, and _please_ became an adverb rather than part of an adverbial phrase.